# delete_object with amazon s3 php sdk

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-s3

Is it possible to delete a folder with the SDK that still contains content?
It is possible to do in the amazon console but doesn't appear to work with the php sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Not Sure What you are asking for , if you want to delete an object completely here is the code for that using Amazon SDK  for PHP,

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'my-bucket' . strtolower($s3->key);

$response = $s3->delete_object($bucket, 'prefix with spaces/åéîøü/åéîøü/åéîøü with  spaces.txt');

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

If you want to delete a specified version of object of S3 then the code here does that

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'my-bucket' . strtolower($s3->key); 
// Delete a specific version 
$response = $s3->delete_object($bucket, 'test1.txt', array('versionId'=>'0NNAq8PwvXvg8EfAYG9sSmwKTZeixZgZNE6PbodG8td0DJ3gVOmjI2Gh/oFnb0Ie=')); 
// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
var_dump(strpos((string) $response->header['_info']['url'], 'versionId=' . $version_id) !== false);
```

You can find still more info on API calls here [AMAZON SDK FOR PHP , API's FOR S3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=AmazonS3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete_bucket()`. There's a parameter that allows you to "force" delete the bucket and all of its contents. There are also `delete_all_objects()` and `delete_all_object_versions()`.